# Provide lodash with mixins globally via webpack.ProvidePlugin

Tags: typescript, lodash, webpack

I have some lodash mixins that I want to provide with webpack.ProvidePlugin, e.g:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export {_};
_.mixin({
  capitalize: function (input: string) {
  bla...
  }
})
```

I'm using Typescript with Webpack.

In webpack.config.js I have:

```
lodashPlugin = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  _: 'common/lodash_mixins'
})
```

When I try to use `_.capitalize(string)`, I get

`TypeError: _.capitalize is not a function`

When I log '_' I see that capitalize is in fact a function on that Object.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting `_` as a named export, that you would require with `import { _ } from 'common/lodash_mixins';`, but ProvidePlugin expects you to export a single object. You should be using a default export instead.

```
export default _;
```

See [default export](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default_exports_%28one_per_module%29).

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: *.capitalize is not a function
>   When I log '*' I see that capitalize is in fact a function on that Object.

log `_.capitalize` you will find it is undefined. If you only log `_` you get the opportunity to see a mutated version (dev tools will allow lazy evaluation). => if this is correct then it leads me to believe that you have a ordering issue somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to work for me is:

```
import * as lodashExtended from 'lodash';
module.exports = lodashExtended;
lodashExtended.mixin({
  capitalize: function (input: string) {
  bla...
  }
})
```

I would prefer a solution that uses es6 syntax but haven't found one as yet.

Thanks to @basarat for help in debugging this.